# How can tell a service resource on Chef to restart only if files in a particul directory have been updated?

Tags: tomcat, chef-infra

I am running tomcat though chef. In my recipe, tomcat is first started, but later on, in the recipe, I transfer files from my cookbook to a directory on my node. When the files have been updated, I need Tomcat to restart, but only if the files have been changed. How can I achieve this?

This is what I have so far:

```rb
#tomcat is currently running

cookbook_file "#{run_dir}/run.conf"  do
  source 'run.conf'
  owner 'tomcat'
  mode '0644'
end

tomcat_service 'default' do
  action [:restart]
  only_if # only if "#{run_dir}/run.conf" has been updated as shown above
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use a functionality called [notifications](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common/#notifications). This allows Chef resources to either notify (`notifies`) or listen (`subscribes`) to other resources for changes.

In your case, if the `cookbook_file` resource changed the `run.conf` on the node, it should "notify" the `tomcat_service` resource to restart.
Example:

```rb
# Tomcat is currently running

cookbook_file "#{run_dir}/run.conf" do
  source 'run.conf'
  owner 'tomcat'
  mode '0644'
  notifies :restart, 'tomcat_service[default]', :delayed
end

tomcat_service 'default' do
  action :nothing
end
```

The notifications can trigger the action `:immediately` or `:delayed`. In the above example, the service restart will be triggered, but at the end of chef-client run (taking into account any other `:restart` actions). If you want to restart immediately after the file changes, you should use `:immediately`.